# How is Thor able to recall Stormbreaker to his hand?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-endgame, stormbreaker

I know that Thor can recall Mjolnir by holding out his hand because Mjolnir has some Asgardian <s>magic</s> science such-and-such in it.

But how is he able to recall Stormbreaker? Is there other stuff he can recall using his hands?

Comment: Can you explain why you believe it couldn't / shouldn't be the same way he recalls Mjolnir? As I see it, science isn't really a concept that would work differently depending on where an object is made. There isn't "Asgardian science," just science.

Comment: @MishaR Because it doesn't have the enchantment like Mjolnir does?

Comment: @MishaR Well we never see him summon anything else to his hand.

Comment: If Mjolnir was also forged by the dwarves of Nidavellir (https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Mj%C3%B8lnir) then there's no reason to assume that Stormbreaker doesn't have similar abilities as Mjolnir.

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR: because it's one of Stormbreaker's many useful features.**

> Thor can recall Mjolnir [...] because Mjolnir has some Asgardian science such-and-such in it.

Actually that sounds more like Nidavellir tech than Asgardian magic. Mjolnir's enchantment tackles the "power of Thor" part, not really Mjolnir's handling. And Thor isn't the god of hammers, he's the god of lightning; telekinesis isn't in his main skillset.

> How is he able to recall Stormbreaker?

Simply put - why not? It's made clear in *Infinity War* that Stormbreaker is a state-of-the-art weapon, one which will help conquer and reign on a battlefield.

> **Rocket**: This is the plan? We're gonna hit him with a brick?
>
> **Eitri**: It's a mold. A king's weapon. Meant to be the greatest in Asgard. In theory, it could even summon the Bifrost.

The "greatest weapon of Asgard" comes with a couple extra features, such as being a teleporter. Going back to their owner's hand doesn't seem too much of a stretch. It *is* extremely handy. (pun intended)

As per your last point, I can't think straight away of anything else he can summon at will.

Answer (score 3):

The ability to recall weapons is a common trope.

[Here](https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Weapon_Calling) are a few examples of weapon calling, and [here](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SummonToHand) is a TVTropes page on the "Summon to Hand" ability.

> When a character has need of his signature weapon, or any other handheld item, he sometimes has the option of summoning it even if it's not nearby. This is usually an explicit power of the item itself, and is probably the most common power in magic weapons after [absurd sharpness](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AbsurdlySharpBlade).

From [the MCU wikia](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Stormbreaker):

> Like Mjølnir before it, Stormbreaker will return to Thor's hand when summoned and strikes his opponents with massive force.

During *Avengers: Endgame*, we see

> Captain America call Mjølnir,

so the recall ability is a property of the weapon itself- Thor does not have the ability to recall any arbitrary weapon or item.

Comment: A good answer but one small nitpick about your last point, when discussing Mjølnir it has been enchanted with all of the powers of Thor, so theoretically anyone who wielded it would be able to use all of Thors powers, such as calling lightning.